# Whats the problem with this code with an xml file?

Tags: android

There are few errors & I am not getting how to get rid of it.

unfortunately, my app is stop this error occurs....

```
Overlapping items in RelativeLayout
  @id/userEmailId can overlap @id/backToLoginBtn if @string/back, @string/submit grow due to localized text expansion  If relative layout has text or button items aligned to left and right sides they can overlap each other due to localized text expansion unless they have mutual constraints like toEndOf/toStartOf.  Issue id: RelativeOverlap

Attribute unused on older version
  Attribute autofillHints is only used in API level 26 and higher (current min is 22)  This check finds attributes set in XML files that were introduced in a version newer than the oldest version targeted by your application (with the minSdkVersion attribute).  This is not an error; the application will simply ignore the attribute. However, if the attribute is important to the appearance or functionality of your application, you should consider finding an alternative way to achieve the same result with only available attributes, and then you can optionally create a copy of the layout in a layout-vNN folder which will be used on API NN or higher where you can take advantage of the newer attribute.  Note: This check does not only apply to attributes. For example, some tags can be unused too, such as the new <tag> element in layouts introduced in API 21.  Issue id: UnusedAttribute

Render Problems
<item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
```

And this is my .xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/registered_emailid"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

 <EditText

    android:id="@+id/login_email"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@drawable/text_selector"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/text_selector"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:hint="@string/email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="#a9a9a9"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />

   <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    />

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/backToLoginBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userEmailId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"

        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />
     </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is the XML file?

Comment: amm, you didn't show any xml code, please add it so we can look for the problem.

Comment: i just posted my XML code

Comment: Hi Kaveri, welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question to include the XML file. Answers are only for answering the original question. Please delete your answer, as it will probably get mod-deleted, but this is not a good thing to happen for new accounts. Also please read [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**how to answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)